# 403 errors when bootstrapping chef

Tags: chef-infra

Client logs:

```
10.41.11.3 Authorization Error:
10.41.11.3 --------------------
10.41.11.3 Your validation client is not authorized to create the client for this node (HTTP 403).
10.41.11.3
10.41.11.3 Possible Causes:
10.41.11.3 ----------------
10.41.11.3 * There may already be a client named "chef02"
10.41.11.3 * Your validation client (chef1-validator) may have misconfigured authorization permissions.

10.41.11.3 [2014-10-24T10:02:50+08:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cac
he/chef-stacktrace.out
10.41.11.3 Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 0.739747653 seconds
10.41.11.3 [2014-10-24T10:02:50+08:00] ERROR: 403 "Forbidden"
10.41.11.3 [2014-10-24T10:02:50+08:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeErr
or: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I have confirmed that no client named "chef02" exists, but I'm stuck on the authorization permissions that may need to be addressed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not authorized for this action when run knife client list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524902/not-authorized-for-this-action-when-run-knife-client-list)

Comment: You should follow [THIS](http://docs.getchef.com/install_server.html) to create proper validation client key and organization. (I've no memory of this kind of message on open source chef server 10 or 11, so I assume it's a version 12)

Comment: @Tensibai , yes I install version 12.

Answer (score 0):

As Chef 12 introduced ACL there could be some problems with gaining access by clients ( https://github.com/chef/chef-server/issues/63 ):

I have the same problem and I resolved it with this command:

`knife acl bulk add group clients nodes '.*' update,read`

( https://github.com/chef/chef-server/issues/63#issuecomment-137766205 )

First install knife acl plugin by issue command: 
`chef gem install knife-acl`

( more info: https://github.com/chef/knife-acl )